# Trying to modify powershell to include combobox to populate listbox

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface

I have a working script that has a single printserver name hard coded into it which populates a listbox. you can click on a printer and click install it and then click to make it the default printer. This works fine but I would like to have a dropdown menu that contains several printservers. when a printserver is chosen from the list it would populate the listbox with all of the printers on that printserver. I have fried everything I can think of to make this work. what am I not getting right Below are the 2 sets of code. Working one first.

**Working Code**

```
   ### Variables

   #Printserver
       $printserver = "Myprintserver"


### Hide PowerShell Console
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)

### GUI
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                     = '350,237'
$Form.text                           = "Printer Install Tool"
$Form.TopMost                        = $false

$btn_Cancel                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Cancel.text                     = "Close"
$btn_Cancel.width                    = 110
$btn_Cancel.height                   = 30
$btn_Cancel.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(202,181)
$btn_Cancel.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btn_Install                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Install.text                    = "Install printer"
$btn_Install.width                   = 110
$btn_Install.height                  = 30
$btn_Install.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(202,101)
$btn_Install.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btn_Default                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Default.text                    = "Set as Default"
$btn_Default.width                   = 110
$btn_Default.height                  = 30
$btn_Default.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(202,141)
$btn_Default.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtBox_Location                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtBox_Location.multiline           = $false
$txtBox_Location.width               = 147
$txtBox_Location.height              = 20
$txtBox_Location.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,35)
$txtBox_Location.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$listBox_Printers                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox_Printers.text               = "listBox"
$listBox_Printers.width              = 159
$listBox_Printers.height             = 192
$listBox_Printers.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,35)

$lbl_ChoosePrinter                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.text              = "Choose a printer"
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.AutoSize          = $true
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.width             = 25
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.height            = 10
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,16)
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lbl_PrinterLoc                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_PrinterLoc.text                 = "Printer location"
$lbl_PrinterLoc.AutoSize             = $true
$lbl_PrinterLoc.width                = 25
$lbl_PrinterLoc.height               = 10
$lbl_PrinterLoc.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,16)
$lbl_PrinterLoc.Font                 = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($btn_Cancel,$btn_Install,$txtBox_Location,$listBox_Printers,$lbl_ChoosePrinter,$lbl_PrinterLoc,$btn_Default))


### Eventhandlers 

$listBox_Printers.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ 
   $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
#write-host $printName
   $txtBox_Location.Text = Get-Printer -ComputerName $printserver -Name $printName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Location"

})

$btn_Default.Add_Click({ 
$printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter("\\$printserver\$printName")
})

$btn_Cancel.Add_Click({ 
   $Form.Close() 
})

$btn_Install.Add_Click({ 
   $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
   get-wmiobject -class win32_printer -computer $printserver
   rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\$printserver\$printName
  
})


### Main
$printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
$printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $printserver | Select-Object -Property "Location", "Name"

foreach($printer in $printers){
   $listBox_Printers.Items.Add($printer.Name)
}


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

**Non working code**

```
    ### Variables

    #Printserver
        $printserver = "$cmbx_Server.SelectedItem"


### Hide PowerShell Console
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)

### GUI
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                     = '350,450'
$Form.text                           = "Printer Install Tool"
$Form.TopMost                        = $false

$lbl_Server                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_Server.text                 = "Print Server"
$lbl_Server.AutoSize             = $true
$lbl_Server.width                = 25
$lbl_Server.height               = 10
$lbl_Server.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,16)
$lbl_Server.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$cmbx_Server                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$cmbx_Server.text                = "Choose Server"
$cmbx_Server.width               = 100
$cmbx_Server.height              = 30
@('Printserver1','Printserver2','Printserver3','Printserver3','Printserver4','Printserver5','Printserver6','Printserver7','Printserver8','Printserver9','Printserver0') | ForEach-Object {[void] $cmbx_Server.Items.Add($_)}
$cmbx_Server.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(6,46)
$cmbx_Server.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$btn_Server                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Server.text                 = "Select Server"
$btn_Server.width                = 150
$btn_Server.height               = 30
$btn_Server.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,46)
$btn_Server.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$btn_Cancel                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Cancel.text                     = "Close"
$btn_Cancel.width                    = 100
$btn_Cancel.height                   = 30
$btn_Cancel.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(225,410)
$btn_Cancel.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btn_Install                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Install.text                    = "Install printer"
$btn_Install.width                   = 100
$btn_Install.height                  = 30
$btn_Install.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,410)
$btn_Install.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btn_Default                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_Default.text                    = "Set as Default"
$btn_Default.width                   = 100
$btn_Default.height                  = 30
$btn_Default.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(117,410)
$btn_Default.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtBox_Location                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtBox_Location.multiline           = $false
$txtBox_Location.width               = 147
$txtBox_Location.height              = 20
$txtBox_Location.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,110)
$txtBox_Location.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'

$listBox_Printers                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox_Printers.text               = "listBox"
$listBox_Printers.width              = 159
$listBox_Printers.height             = 192
$listBox_Printers.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,110)

$lbl_ChoosePrinter                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.text              = "Choose a printer"
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.AutoSize          = $true
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.width             = 25
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.height            = 10
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,90)
$lbl_ChoosePrinter.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lbl_PrinterLoc                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_PrinterLoc.text                 = "Printer location"
$lbl_PrinterLoc.AutoSize             = $true
$lbl_PrinterLoc.width                = 25
$lbl_PrinterLoc.height               = 10
$lbl_PrinterLoc.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,90)
$lbl_PrinterLoc.Font                 = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($btn_Cancel,$btn_Install,$txtBox_Location,$listBox_Printers,$lbl_ChoosePrinter,$lbl_PrinterLoc,$btn_Default,$lbl_Server,$cmbx_Server,$btn_Server))


### Eventhandlers 

$cmbx_Server.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
        write-host $cmbx_Server.text
})
$listBox_Printers.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ 
    $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
#write-host $printName
    $txtBox_Location.Text = Get-Printer -ComputerName $printserver -Name $printName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Location"

})

$btn_Default.Add_Click({ 
Get-PSDrive
Set-Location 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows'
Get-ItemProperty -path .
Set-ItemProperty -path . -name "LegacyDefaultPrinterMode" -value 1
c:
$printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter("\\$printserver\$printName")
})

$btn_Server.Add_Click({$listBox_Printers.Text = $cmbx_Server.SelectedItem("Get-printer -Computername $printserver")})
    
#})

$btn_Cancel.Add_Click({ 
    $Form.Close() 
})

$btn_Install.Add_Click({ 
    $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
    #get-wmiobject -class win32_printer -computer $printserver
    #rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\$printserver\$printName
   Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$printServer\$printName
})


### Main
$printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
$printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $printserver | Select-Object -Property "Location", "Name"

foreach($printer in $cmbx_Server.SelectedItem){
    $listBox_Printers.Items.Add($printer.Name)
}


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Well… it is not clear what “printers” you want displayed in the list box when print server X is selected in the combo box. We can see the combo box is “manually” filled with 10 print server names, however, in the combo boxes selected index changed event… it appears the code simply prints the print server name that was selected? In other words, how is the code going to know which printers to put into the list box without some “key” that associates THAT printer to a particular print server. I do not see any of this.

Comment: Typically, you would have either one or two tables… possibly one table with a list of print servers with a unique print server ID. We would use this table as a `DataSource` for the combo box as opposed to “manually” adding the items. Then a second table of Printers such that each printer has a print server ID associated with it. This would be the list boxes data source. Then when the combo boxes selected index changes, the code would “filter” the list boxes data source to contain only printers that have the same print server ID.

Comment: A `BindingSource` should simplify filtering the list box data source. I hope this makes sense. So… “how” is the data for the print servers AND printers obtained and what type of data structure(s) are they? What fields exist in the data? Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: get-printer -computername myprintserver is the command used to list all of the shared printers

Comment: _”get-printer -computername myprintserver is the command used to list all of the shared printers”_ … Ahh… OK we are glad you got it working Good Luck.

Comment: No it is ot working that was a response to your comment "Well… it is not clear what “printers” you want displayed"  I can make this work just fine with a single printserver name  as $printserver = "Myprintserver". the issue I am having is trying to use a combobox to pass a server name as a variable to populate the listbox with the printers on the selested printer.

Comment: _”... the issue I am having is trying to use a combobox to pass a server name as a variable to populate the listbox with the printers on the selested printer.”_ … Well it appears you have the combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event wired up with… `$cmbx_Server.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ …` … But it appears all the code does is display the print server name to the text box… `write-host $cmbx_Server.text` … ? … would not the `$cmbx_Server.text` give you what you are looking for?

Comment: I started over from scratch and finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static ex`enter code here`tern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
    '
    $consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
    #[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
    
    ### GUI
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    
    $Form                                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize                     = '700,450'
    $Form.text                           = "Printer Installation Tool"
    $Form.TopMost                        = $false
    
    $cmbx_server                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    #$cmbx_server.text                = "Printserver1"
    $cmbx_server.width               = 130
    $cmbx_server.height              = 20
    @('Printserver1','Printserver2','Printserver3') | ForEach-Object {[void] $cmbx_server.Items.Add($_)}
    $cmbx_server.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,59)
    $cmbx_server.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    
    $lbl_Server                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $lbl_Server.text                 = "Choose Server"
    $lbl_Server.AutoSize             = $true
    $lbl_Server.width                = 25
    $lbl_Server.height               = 10
    $lbl_Server.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,16)
    $lbl_Server.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    
    $btn_Cancel                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn_Cancel.text                     = "Close"
    $btn_Cancel.width                    = 110
    $btn_Cancel.height                   = 30
    $btn_Cancel.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,400)
    $btn_Cancel.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    $btn_Install                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn_Install.text                    = "Install printer"
    $btn_Install.width                   = 100
    $btn_Install.height                  = 30
    $btn_Install.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,310)
    $btn_Install.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    $btn_Remove                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn_Remove.text                    = "Remove Printer"
    $btn_Remove.width                   = 120
    $btn_Remove.height                  = 30
    $btn_Remove.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(375,310)
    $btn_Remove.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    $lbl_Note                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $lbl_Note.text                 = "Note: Cannot remove Default Printer"
    $lbl_Note.AutoSize             = $true
    $lbl_Note.width                = 300
    $lbl_Note.height               = 10
    $lbl_Note.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,340)
    $lbl_Note.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    
    $txtBox_Location                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $txtBox_Location.multiline           = $false
    $txtBox_Location.width               = 147
    $txtBox_Location.height              = 20
    $txtBox_Location.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,59)
    $txtBox_Location.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'
    
    $listBox_Printers                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox_Printers.text               = ""
    $listBox_Printers.width              = 275
    $listBox_Printers.height             = 192
    $listBox_Printers.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,120)
    
    $listBox_Local_Printers                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox_Local_Printers.text               = ""
    $listBox_Local_Printers.width              = 310
    $listBox_Local_Printers.height             = 192
    $listBox_Local_Printers.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(375,120)
    
    $lbl_Local_Printer                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $lbl_Local_Printer.text              = "Installed Printers"
    $lbl_Local_Printer.AutoSize          = $true
    $lbl_Local_Printer.width             = 25
    $lbl_Local_Printer.height            = 10
    $lbl_Local_Printer.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,95)
    $lbl_Local_Printer.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.text              = "Available Network Printers"
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.AutoSize          = $true
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.width             = 25
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.height            = 10
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,95)
    $lbl_ChoosePrinter.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    $lbl_PrinterLoc                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.text                 = "Printer location"
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.AutoSize             = $true
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.width                = 25
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.height               = 10
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(179,16)
    $lbl_PrinterLoc.Font                 = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    
    ### Set as Default Button
    $btn_Default                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn_Default.text                  = "Set as Default"
    $btn_Default.AutoSize              = $false
    $btn_Default.width                 = 110
    $btn_Default.height                = 30
    $btn_Default.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(575,310)
    $btn_Default.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    
    ### Refresh button
    $btn_Refresh                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btn_Refresh.text                  = "Refresh"
    $btn_Refresh.AutoSize              = $false
    $btn_Refresh.width                 = 80
    $btn_Refresh.height                = 30
    $btn_Refresh.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(495,310)
    $btn_Refresh.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
        
    $Form.controls.AddRange(@($lbl_Note, $btn_Remove, $btn_Refresh, $btn_Cancel,$btn_Install,$txtBox_Location,$listBox_Printers,$lbl_ChoosePrinter,$lbl_PrinterLoc,$cmbx_server,$lbl_server,$btn_Default,$listBox_Local_Printers,$lbl_Local_Printer))
    
    ### Eventhandlers 
    $cmbx_server.Add_SelectedValueChanged({ 
        $global:printserver = $cmbx_server.Items[$cmbx_server.SelectedIndex]
        DisplayPrinters
    })
    
    $listBox_Printers.Add_SelectedValueChanged({ $cmbx_Server
        $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem
        $txtBox_Location.Text = Get-Printer -ComputerName $global:printserver -Name $printName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Location"
    })
    
    $btn_Default.Add_Click({ 
        $printName = $listBox_Local_Printers.SelectedItem
        SetPrinterAsDefault $printName
    })
    
    $btn_Remove.Add_Click({ 
        $printName = $listBox_Local_Printers.SelectedItem
        Remove-Printer $printName
    })
    
    $btn_Refresh.Add_Click({ 
        DisplayPrinters
    })
    
    $btn_Cancel.Add_Click({ 
        $Form.Close() 
    })
    
    $btn_Install.Add_Click({ 
        $printName = $listBox_Printers.SelectedItem    
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$global:printserver\$printName
        #SetPrinterAsDefault \\$global:printserver\$printName
    })
    
    Function SetPrinterAsDefault($printName){
        Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" -name "LegacyDefaultPrinterMode" -value 1
        if($printName -like "*(Default Printer)"){
            #Printer is already default
            DisplayPrinters
            return
        }
        $printInfo = Get-Printer $printName
        if($printInfo -ne $null){
            if($printInfo.Type -eq "Local"){
                $printer = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='$printName'"
                Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $printer -MethodName SetDefaultPrinter
            }
            else{
                (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter("$printName")
            }
        }
        DisplayPrinters
    }
    
    Function DisplayPrinters(){
        #Remove all old
        $listBox_Printers.Items.Clear()
        $listBox_local_Printers.Items.Clear()
    
        $printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $global:printserver | Select-Object -Property "Location", "Name"
        foreach($printer in $printers){
            $listBox_Printers.Items.Add($printer.Name) | Out-Null
        }
    
        $defaultPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | select -ExpandProperty name
    
        $local_printers = Get-Printer | Select-Object Name
        foreach($printer in $local_printers){
            if($printer.Name -eq $defaultPrinter){
                $printer.name = $printer.name + " (Default Printer)"
            }
            $listBox_local_Printers.Items.Add($printer.Name) | Out-Null
        }
    }
    ### Main
    $cmbx_server.text = $cmbx_server.Items[0]
    
    [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```